# mpglib_interface.c 'interface.h' file not found

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

I an trying to compile the WunderRadio app source code available here http://dev.wunderground.com/support/wunderradio/wunderradio.1.9lgpl.zip. After making all the modifications to the project to compile on iOS5 i get the following error:

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'interface.h' file not found.
```

Of course i tried getting the interface.h from the lame library that i previously downloaded, and added it to the project with no luck. Apparently its not the right file.

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I found this file at:

http://code.google.com/p/live-converter/source/browse/trunk/include/interface.h?r=13

Comment: That file did not work.. are you compiling the same source as i do, the one from wunderradio ?

Comment: I gave up. I read somewhere (don't remember where) that there are missing files intentionally. I will be happy to hear that I am wrong!

Comment: Most probably, but it is not the only developers that do change something in porpouse not anybody to compile their app that easy.. its a way for protecting the developer community, i can understand

Comment: Yes, I can understand, but it is illegal and against the GPL license that ffmpeg is distribute with.